# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.DataVisualization MEF MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, mef

I am creating a website which should be able to take in multiple modules and compose those modules to a main project. After programming the bootstrapper and custom View engine to make it able to find Views in the module.dll.

After compiling a test module for testing, I am getting a weird error where it says it cannot load System.Web.DataVisualization for some reason. I have also noticed that the Controller from the Module dll gets loaded properly, I can see it in the debug but this error keeps killing a thread and throws the error.

[image]

This is the code I have for Bootstrapper.cs that handles the loading/composing of the dlls.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.IO;

public class Bootstrapper
{
    private static CompositionContainer CompositionContainer;
    private static bool IsLoaded = false;

    public static void Compose(List<string> pluginFolders)
    {   
        if (IsLoaded) return;

        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin")));

        foreach (var plugin in pluginFolders)
        {
            var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Modules", plugin));
            catalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

        }
        CompositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        CompositionContainer.ComposeParts();
        IsLoaded = true;
    }

    public static T GetInstance<T>(string contractName = null)
    {
        var type = default(T);
        if (CompositionContainer == null) return type;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contractName))
            type = CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>(contractName);
        else
            type = CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>();

        return type;
    }
}
```

And this is the error that gets thrown out when testing.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was to unfortunately manually download the dll and add it to the reference, but the main edit was to Web.Config where I had to define the assembly to import `System.Web.DataVisualization` as such.         `<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />`